# Rails after_save is not working (rails - 3.2.22.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have OrderItem, SaleOrderItem and PurchaseOrderItem model

```
class SaleOrderItem < OrderItem
  self.table_name = "order_items"
end

class PurchaseOrderItem < OrderItem
   self.table_name = "order_items"
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :update_order

  def update_order
    is_pending = ord.order_items.
      where(state: [SaleOrderItem.on_orde, SaleOrderItem.carter]).count > 0
    self.order.update_column(:any_pending_order_items, is_pending)
  end
end
```

After save method is not called in the following case

```
so = SaleOrder.first
oi = so.order_items.first
oi.save   << This is not calling after_save on order items
```

After save method is called in the following case

```
oi2 = OrderItem.find(oi.id)
oi2.save << This calls after_save on order items
```

Anyone any comments?

Comment: Can you show your model, specifically the after_save callback declaration and the method being called? For some basic trouble shooting use `io.save!` to fail loudly.

Comment: You sure it didn't call `after_save`? `oi` and `oi2` are the same, aren't they?

Comment: @user3366016 
I have added more info to the question and I have added the solution found. Sorry for fewer details and thanks for the time you spend to help me.

Comment: @EJ2015  I have added more info to the question and I have added the solution found. Sorry for fewer details and thanks for the time you spend to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution
The after_save method should be called on both SaleOrderItem and PurchaseOrderItem model rather than OrderItem model. So it should be like following

```
class SaleOrderItem < OrderItem
  after_save :update_order << Here after_save added
  self.table_name = "order_items"
end

class PurchaseOrderItem < OrderItem
   after_save :update_order << Here after_save added
   self.table_name = "order_items"
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
              << Here after_save removed
  def update_order
    is_pending = ord.order_items.
      where(state: [SaleOrderItem.on_orde, SaleOrderItem.carter]).count > 0
    self.order.update_column(:any_pending_order_items, is_pending)
  end
end
```

This will fix after_save is not called in some cases